# ASP.NET Web API : iterating over sections of multipart/form-data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.8

ASP.NET Core has a library class for iterating multi-part forms `MultipartReader`.

I would like to iterate multi-part forms in an older ASP.NET Web API (.NET 4.8) in a similar fashion.

There is `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` but when I call `Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider)` it reads all sections to the output stream instead of allowing me to iterate each section.

Are there any classes for ASP.NET Web API that allow me to handle multi-part forms similar to what ASP.NET Core does?